# Anyway I can publish...faster?

Tags: actionscript-3

[image]

Any time I want to test out my app (and it's fairly large) I have to debug it on my smart phone. I cant use the mobile simulator built into animate because it has a bunch of ANEs that are dependent on Google Play Services. Is there a faster way to do this vs converting everything to ARM code every time?

Comment: If your project setup allows it, you can move your code base to Flash Builder. It pre-caches your builds so you only have to do incremental compilations (every compilation is faster than the previous one).

Comment: Is it as simple as importing an Fla? I read an article from 2012 that I could use Flash to design and Flash Builder to code. Is that still possible?

Comment: @Mr.Phantom is Animate already doing this? I notice a lot of tmp files piling up from what I can only assume come from my builds https://snag.gy/LwliGc.jpg

Comment: I haven't used Animate/Pro in many years. I remember that Flash Pro kept like a backup copy of your project (like Word and Excel does). But I don't really know if they cache the compilation builds. What I meant about the project setup is that if you don't use the time line, library or other Animate features, you might as well code your project in an IDE. In Flash Builder there's an option to connect to Flash Pro, but I never tested it.